# Applet doesn't save results to database on localhost

Tags: java, mysql, database, applet, localhost

I try to put a Java Applet on localhost. Everything is okay to the time of saving results in MySQL DB. When I do it in Netbeans everything is ok and the saving of results works perfect. The problem shows during code execution on localhost, results don't want to save in database. There's no an error, no info about it.

This is the code:

```
public void connection() {
        try{           
            String s1 = l10.getText();
            String s2 = l11.getText();
            String s3 = l12.getText();
            String s4 = l13.getText();
            String s5 = l14.getText();
            String s6 = l15.getText();

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/draw", "root", "");

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        String insert = "INSERT INTO draw VALUES ('" + s1 + "', '" + s2 + "', '" + s3 + "', '" + s4 + "', '" + s5 + "', '" + s6 + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(insert);

        int msg2= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                              "Saved", 
                              "Waring!", 
                              JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        int msg= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                              "No connection with database\n" + e, 
                              "Warning!", 
                              JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: can it be blamed to the fact you should be doing a commit and connection close ?

Comment: Any reason why you are using an applet in 2015 instead of JNLP?

Answer (score 0):

Here `INSERT` query in table `draw` you must check your `DataType` matches with input and you must write the field names while inserting like

```
INSERT into draw ('') values('');
```

Comment: It's something wrong in this place: 
`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/draw", "root", "");
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();`
I've made message boxex and in this place execution stops and do nothing then.

Comment: I think you have have mention port number of your Localhost i.e
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/draw"